# crontabs not firing on mac osx server under a non root account

Tags: mac-osx-server, cron, opendirectory, launchctl

I'd like to run a crontab but it is never fired. It's on a mac osx server 10.5.6

Accounts on mac are not defined in /etc/passwd. So their is no use in adding my account in /usr/lib/cron/cron.allow. I tryed just in case, but nothing changed. Crontab man says that I could make an empty  /usr/lib/cron/cron.deny so that all users can fire their cron jobs, but I don't want other users to be able to make crontabs.

Is their a solution or should I use launchctl, which looks far from simple?

Comment: Is the cron daemon running?  Launchd should start it as soon as you create a crontab file, but it's worth checking.  Run `ps -ax | grep [c]ron` to find out.

Comment: yes it does. I also tryed with an empty /usr/lib/cron/cron.deny with no /usr/lib/cron/cron.allow, but nothing happened.